# Retrieving Kafka Producer config

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to collect Kafka Producer configs from the Kafka cluster? 
I know that these settings are stored on the client itself.
I am interested at least in `client.id` and a collection of topics that the producer is publishing to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool provided by Apache Kafka (or Confluent) to acquire this information.

I worked on a team that built a tool called the [Stream Registry](https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/stream-registry) that did provide a centralized location for this information

Answer (score 0):

May be you can have a look into kafkacat.[github url](http://%20https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat)
We find it very helpful in troubleshooting, kafka issues.